# sorting array of object in backbone js or underscore js

Tags: model-view-controller, backbone.js, underscore.js

```
[
    {"group_id":1,"name":"All Area","parent_id":0,"date_created":1250172000,"type":"area","description":null},
    {"group_id":2,"name":"IT","parent_id":5,"date_created":1250172000,"type":"area","description":null},
    {"group_id":3,"name":"BPO","parent_id":5,"date_created":1250172000,"type":"area","description":null},
    {"group_id":4,"name":"Engineering","parent_id":5,"date_created":1250172000,"type":"area","description":null},
    {"group_id":5,"name":"Baroda","parent_id":6,"date_created":1250172000,"type":"site","description":null},
    {"group_id":6,"name":"Gujarat","parent_id":0,"date_created":1250172000,"type":"site","description":null},
    {"group_id":7,"name":"Surat","parent_id":10,"date_created":1250172000,"type":"site","description":null},
    {"group_id":8,"name":"IT","parent_id":7,"date_created":1250172000,"type":"site","description":null},
    {"group_id":9,"name":"Ahemadabad","parent_id":10,"date_created":1250172000,"type":"site","description":null},
]
```

I want to generate one list of all the data using backbone js or underscore js in such a way that each item comes under its parent.

i.e. Here data with name 'Gujarat' should come first as it has no parent. Underneath that item name with Baroda should come. Under Baroda, item names whose parent_id is group_id of Baroda should come i.e (item with group_id 2,3,4). Under Surat will come all its children. As seen, parent_id of Surat and Ahemdadabad is 10 but there is no item with group_id 
of 10 listed here. So Surat and Ahemdadabad also become main items.

All data should be placed in one unorder-list.

Please see below for the output format. I need to generate a view in backbone using this model data.

All areas

Gujarat

Baroda

IT

BPO

Engineering

Surat

IT

Ahemadabad

Does anyone has solution for this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: anyone ? or need some more explanation !!

Comment: what have you tried yourself? this is not a "job posting" board but a "i tried this and it doesn't work, could you take a look at what i'm doing wrong" board

Comment: Sorry @sander, but I am new to backbone.js and I m not getting how should I sort this json data in backbone so as I get the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you go read up on Backbone collections here:

http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-collection/

and if you need info on how to sort or filter you can find helper functions here: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-Underscore-Methods (especially the collection.sortBy should be of help)

**remark**

Sorry i was so blunt in the comment, but this is a platform specifically for people with a problem / error on which other people can comment what the solution can be, we are not here to write a whole page for you.

Comment: thanks, let me check the doc and do the code, I understand your concern, I will post the code if my problem persist.

Comment: I have of more recent released more information on  collections http://backbonetutorials.com/nodejs-restify-mongodb-mongoose/